# Vue.js non-progressive rendering

Tags: vue.js

I've been working with Vue SPAs for a little while now and one thing I don't like is how pages are progressively rendered - meaning that the elements are rendered as the page loads, resulting in a choppy user experience. Even with Nuxt SSR - the page is not presented to the user in its entirety, but does a choppy visual load.

Will this problem be minimized when I move my app to production? (is it a 'dev' thing?)
Any way to prevent this apart from the following techniques?

- Use an overlay to hide the page content until everything is loaded.
- Prerender all the pages on the server (I have not tried this yet)

Answer (score 0):

if you are loading data from from created function like this

```
created(){
        axios.get('/api/user').then(response=>{
            this.user = response.data
        })

    },
```

you just need to declare a loading data

```
data: () => ({
loading:true,
user:null
})
```

then on your template

```
<v-overlay :value="loading">
  <v-progress-circular indeterminate size="64" color="yellow"></v-progress-circular>
</v-overlay>
```

the initial value of loading is true that means the overlay will be rendered
when the website load you just need to set the value loading to false after you fetch your data, just add :

```
created(){
        axios.get('/api/user').then(response=>{
            this.user = response.data
            this.loading = false
        })

    },
```

since the loading data will be used almost for all the routes I suggest that you used  [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for the loading data so that it can be used in all components.

if you are not loading any data you can look at vuejs [lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)

Comment: Thanks for the input but I'm not talking about async data - I'm talking about how the page progressively renders elements resulting in a choppy visual page load.